# 4 questions about idiomatic way of expressing

Tags: idioms

Yesterday, a six-year-old girl was found dead in a septic tank of a demolition site. The preliminary analysis given by the police was that this had a sheer accident.

Q1: "a six-year-old girl was found dead in" and "the dead body of a six-year-old girl was found in". Which is better?

Q2: Is there any difference between "demolition site" and "construction site"?

Q3: preliminary analysis, Can I use preliminary investigation or preliminary conclusion instead?

Q4: a sheer accident,  I don't think it's idiomatic. What about an accident only?

Comment: I note that there are votes to close this Q. on the grounds that "Proofreading questions are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified." Surely OP has identified **4 specific** "sources of concern"?

Comment: This doesn't come across as a proofreading question to me. The OP has specific questions about different wordings and the implications thereof.

Answer (score 2):

Q1. "A six year old girl was found dead in" is better because it's gentler. "The dead body of a six year old girl" places emphasis on the body rather than on the girl. That comes across as callous under the circumstances. Also, "dead body" verges on the redundant; "the body of a six year old girl" would be sufficient to convey that she is dead.

Q2. Technically, a construction site is where something is being built and a demolition site, where it's being torn down. That said, I think that in casual conversation most people would not distinguish between the two. An old structure is being demolished near my house. When I give people directions, I typically say "you'll see a construction site on your right", even though "demolition site" is more pedantically exact. Such pedantic exactitude is probably necessary for a news report, though.

Q3. "Preliminary conclusion" is acceptable because it's passed into common use. However, it's grating. "Preliminary" implies opening, "conclusion" closing; the whole phrase seems like a contradiction in terms. As suggested by @mplungjan, "preliminary findings" is much better.

Q4. The phrase is indeed unidiomatic. "Sheer accident" is used for trivialities: "I was worried because I was late for work, but by sheer accident my boss was even later than I." It's not used for a tragic event. Your hunch that "accident" by itself is better is well-founded.

There are other problems with the last sentence. The pluperfect isn't used in that way in English; "this was an accident" would sound more natural. But the antecedent of "this" is unclear--does it refer to the girl's death, or the discovery of her body? The passive voice in "given by the police" doesn't sound natural either. "According to the police, a preliminary analysis suggests accidental death" would be preferable.

Comment: I wish I could give 10 votes to this answer.